# Azure ADB2C redirecting to wrong domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have following situation:
I'm trying to integrate ADB2C with my SPA app in backend:

```
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddApiKeySupport(options => { });

        services.AddOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme).Configure<IGraphServiceClient, ILogRepository>((options, graphClient, logRepo) =>
        {
            var oldPostValidate = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
            {
                await new AzureADB2CHelper(graphClient).OnTokenValidated(context);
                await oldPostValidate(context);
            };


        });
```

Also I set configuration:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://rqrar.b2clogin.com/",
    "Domain": "rqrar.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "guid",
    "ClientId": "guid",
    "CallbackPath": "/api/response-oidc",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SIGN_IN",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PASSWORD_RESET",
  }
```

In app registration I have application with redirect uri: https://custom-domain.com/api/response-oidc
And now if user will correctly login I'm expecting he will be redirected to https://custom-domain.com/api/response-oidc instead of this ADB2C is trying redirect user to https://default-generated-url-by-azure.azurewebsites.net/api/response-oidc

Have anyone idea what can I missing ?

Comment: Please refer [Enable custom domains for Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I don't want have custom domain as url to AD  I just want login flow will redirect me after successful login to https://custom-domain.com instead of https://default-generated-url-by-azure.azurewebsites.net